# Remove focus from input on click outside

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I'm using Flex 4.6 with spark components. I have form with DropDownList, and I want to achieve next behaviour:

*user clicks on text input in DropDownList -> DropDownList get focus*

*user clicks outside (on background Rect, for example) -> DropDownList lose focus*

Suddenly, second part doesn't work from box. DropDownList still in focus when user clicks outside the text input. How to implement required behaviour?

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <fx:Script><![CDATA[
        ]]></fx:Script>
    <s:TextInput />
</s:Application>
```

If you click on TextInput it gets focus. And you cannot remove this focus by clicking outside TextInput.

Comment: Post some code showing what you've tried so far.

Comment: What you have added is not the code that @Brian meant. You should put the code which you have tried to resolve your problem ( remove the focus after clicking outside the TextInput ) ... BTW, think to `stage.focus` ...

Comment: I'm looking for solution from the box. Like some missing properties or configurations. Of course, it's possible to implement it over default behavior, but I hoped that some common known solution exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution at the official forum. There is a [post](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/929216) with same problem. 
And working solution in the end:

```
textInput.addEventListener(FocusEvent.MOUSE_FOCUS_CHANGE, textInputMouseFocusChange, false, 0, true);
// basically the above Event will dispatch when ever the user clicked outside of textinput when the current focus in in textInput.

private function textInputMouseFocusChange(event:FocusEvent):void {
// basically u dont need this first line if u are not calling any function on textInput focusout.

    textInput.dispatchEvent(new FocusEvent(FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT));

// the remaing peice of code will remove the current focus from textInput to the area where the user had clicked.
// this piece of code i have taken from one of the comments in the blog : http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/09/23/setting-focus-in-flex-using-the-focus-manager/

    var focusPoint:Point = new Point();
    focusPoint.x = stage.mouseX;
    focusPoint.y = stage.mouseY;
    var i:int = (stage.getObjectsUnderPoint(focusPoint).length);
    stage.focus=InteractiveObject(stage.getObjectsUnderPoint(focusPoint)[i-1].parent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think that you are speaking about the [`ComboBox`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/ComboBox.html) spark component and not the [`DropDownList`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DropDownList.html) because you have mentioned the `TextInput` of the component which is a `Label` control in the case of a `DropDownList`.

Then, to remove the focus from the `ComboBox` component, you can set the `stage.focus` to `null` when the change event of your component is fired :

```
<s:ComboBox change="on_Change(event)" />
```

And

```
protected function on_Change(event:Event):void
{
    stage.focus = null;
}
```

Hope that can help.